# Python module not loading from a script

Tags: python, linux, winrm

I just installed python-pywinrm trough my package manager, localed in `/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/winrm/`

But when trying to load with `from winrm.protocol import Protocol` on script called with `#/usr/bin/env python` (with defaults to `/usr/bin/python`) I get the module not found error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'winrm.protocol'; 'winrm' is not a package`

But when running this from a pyhton interactive shell it works:

```
-> % python
Python 3.6.1 (default, Mar 27 2017, 00:27:06)
[GCC 6.3.1 20170306] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from winrm.protocol import Protocol
>>>
```

Why is this? I am not running in a Virtualenv.

Comment: Show the `which python`.

Comment: /usr/bin/python